# How can I configure SDL 2.0 to be used with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sdl

I found a tutorial here:
http://twinklebeardev.blogspot.com/2012/07/lesson-0-setting-up-sdl.html

However, I'm not experienced enough to be able to follow these directions. Can anyone help me out with an in depth step by step explanation?

I've already downloaded the three files found here:
http://www.libsdl.org/index.php

Comment: So I guess I need to download the source from mercurial? Do I need a client for this? What do I do with that download?

Comment: I suggest you start with SDL 1.2. which is tested and is already "compiled"

Comment: Thanks Armin. However, I am working on a collaborative project and my peers require the use of 2.0. I actually already had VC++ set up to use 1.2.

A speedy answer would be much appreciated, as I would love to dive into learning SDL as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Armin: They have [SDL2 release candidate binaries](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/download-2.0.php) up nowadays.

Comment: @genpfault Looks like a stable release was published about a week ago. Can you give a broad comparison of 1.2 and 2.0. Is it worth switching to 2.0? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Create an empty VS2012 project ("`sdl-test`") in `c:/temp`.  I recommend unchecking "Create directory for solution".
2. Download [`SDL2-devel-2.0.0-VC.zip`](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.0-VC.zip)
3. Extract contents of `SDL2-devel-2.0.0-VC.zip/SDL2-2.0.0/lib/x86` into `c:/temp/sdl-test/lib`
4. Extract contents of `SDL2-devel-2.0.0-VC.zip/SDL2-2.0.0/include` into `c:/temp/sdl-test/include/SDL2`
5. Open `Configuration Properties`
6. Add `include` to `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`
7. Add `lib` to `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`
8. Add `SDL2main.lib` and `SDL2.lib` to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`
9. Change `Linker -> System -> SubSystem` to `Console` or `Windows`.
10. Add code, using `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`.
11. Copy `lib/SDL2.dll` to your `Debug` and `Release` output directories.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression I needed to compile the source. Thanks for making things simple.